# How to ensure spring configuration can only be loaded once?

Tags: spring

I am wondering how to make sure spring configuration file is loaded only once. Any setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be configure some kind of bean with an static conter variable that count how often it is initzalized.

If this counter is more then zero if the bean is created, then this constrain it volated and an exception should be thorwn.

```
@Component
public OnlyOneInstanceGuard() {

   private static int instanceCounter = 0;


   public OnlyOneInstanceGuard() {
      if(!isFirstInstance) {
         throw new RuntimeException(
            "is not the first instance, let the spring context crash!");
      }
   }

   private syncronized isFirstInstance() {
       instanceCounter++;
       return instanceCounter == 1;
   }
}
```